# Co-homology Groups of the Torus

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, riemann-surfaces

I wanted to explain to me, or give me a reference of how to calculate the
cohomology groups of the complex and real, torus $\mathbb{T}^2$.
I want to use this as an example in a seminar that I will present to my teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Poincaré duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality). The torus is a closed oriented manifold so that the $k$-cohomology group is isomorphic to the $n-k$-th homology group: $H^k (\mathbb T^2) \cong H_{n-k} (\mathbb T^2)$. Then just compute the simplicial homology of the torus.

Comment: I feel Poincare duality is overkill in this situation. It's simple enough to give the torus a simplicial/$\Delta$/cell structure and compute the corresponding cohomology directly.

Comment: @MihaHabič I am not sure one can fill 2 hours of seminar lecture with computations of cohomology groups. But what I wrote is probably overkill. I wrote it because I have never computed cohomology groups but I know how to do simplicial homology for the torus. : )